# Using local storage in Chrome as a DB?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm having success setting/getting data via local storage. Essentially I'm building a reminder extension/geo-location that allows a user to save the url, their geo-location, and title of the url. 3 pieces of data needs to be saved each time. I'm using JSON.stringfy and JSON.parse to do this. Here is where I'm stuck:

1. How do I save each entry from the user without writing over the last entry in local storage? Each time I save the url it doesn't save it in local storage as a new entry. It just keeps saving over the last entry.
2. Over time, the user will probably have dozens of entries, but I want to be able to update specific entries in the dataset. (e.g. if [one of the stored urls in the dataset] == [the url that is presently in the browser url $(location).attr('href');] then do something.

I started with something very simple. Saving and getting data is working.

```
//save my data
var mydata = { urlTitle: myTitle, myurl: currentUrl, urlLoc: geoUrl }​​​​​​​;
localStorage.setItem("mydata", JSON.stringify(mydata));

//get my data
var returnData = localStorage.getItem("mydata");
mydata = JSON.parse(returnData);
```

Just need a bit of guidance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[localStorageDB](https://github.com/knadh/localStorageDB) does exactly this.

```
// Setup database
var lib = new localStorageDB("library", localStorage);
lib.createTable("books", ["code", "title", "author", "year", "copies"]);

// Insert rows
lib.insert("books", {code: "B001", title: "Phantoms in the brain", author: "Ramachandran", year: 1999, copies: 10});
lib.commit();

// Query rows
lib.query("books", {author: "ramachandran"});
```

Disclosure: I authored the library

Comment: No need to thank -- that's what accepting and upvoting are for.

Comment: @Nadh, one thing I've noticed is that I'm only able to see the files I've stored in localstorage by domain. So if I stored a set of urls under the domain hello.com I can only retrieve data if I'm the active tab is set to hello.com. If the active tab is on a different domain (e.g. goodbye.com, adios.com) I can't retrieve the data stored under hello.com. How do i retrieve all data no matter what domain is in the active tab?

Comment: @oxtail, that is impossible by design! Just like cookies, localStorage is on a per domain basis. Otherwise, any site could access any other site's data.

Comment: @nadh Thanks for the info. I figured that since the source of the saving was coming from the same source (my extension), I'd be able to retrieve the list of data that was saved from the same source. BTW your localStorageDB is quite awesome.