# HTML load Data from a local SQL file

Tags: javascript, html, sql, xamarin, local

I made a simple iOS App with Xamarin with a WebView to load local HTML code and run it. Now i want to add a local SQL file and generate a HTML table from its data. It should run on an iPad without Internet Connection.
How can i connect my .html with a local database, so i can create a table from its data?

Comment: Ok. Do you have a question? Please read this guide to asking a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: a local SQL file ... please explain

Comment: Sry i am really new with SQL. I just want to add a local database like SQLite to my Project. And then i want to load its data into a html table. I just ask for any tips what i should use.

Comment: You car refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720783/using-local-storage-in-chrome-as-a-db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all are using Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.iOS?

This links will help to add SQL database to your app: [Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/), [iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/data/sqlite/create_a_database_with_sqlitenet/).

To connect your .html with a database data use [MVVM](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/). Read DB data in your model, then in view create html code and use [LoadHtmlString](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/webview/) to load it to web view.

P.S. Please improve your question and add your WebView code in order to help you in more efficient way.

Comment: Thanks, i am using Xamarin.iOS. Thats a good idea, i will try it this way.